# Uneven table in the last column

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I use quite a lot of (simple) tabular tables. Unfortunately the last column is always a little bit wonky: the text is a few mm higher than in the other columns, just enough to really notice it. How do I evenly center my text horizontally and vertically in my tables?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,numbers=endperiod]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm,footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{N}{@{}m{0pt}@{}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Analogie zwischen Phonologie und Graphematik}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{ | M{4.9cm} | M{4.9cm} | M{4.9cm} | N }
\hline
    &
    \textit{Signifié} &
    \textit{Signifiant} \\[5pt]
\hline
    Sprechsprache &
    \textipa{/a/} (Phonem) &
    \textipa{[a]} (Phon) \\[5pt]
\hline
    Schriftsprache &
    \flq a\frq\space (Graphem) &
    \textvertline a\textvertline\space (Graph) \\[5pt]
\hline
\end{tabular}
    \label{phonographe}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Edit: here is the table with the `\tipa{}` as it looks for me now:
[image: Problem Table]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,numbers=endperiod]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm,footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[footnote,printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Konsonantische Alternationen bei der Pluralbildung}
    \newcommand{\heightadjustment}{\rule[-12pt]{0pt}{2.5\normalbaselineskip}}
\begin{tabular}{ | M{2.7cm} | M{6cm} | M{6cm} | }
\hline
     &
    Singular &
    Plural \\
\hline
    \glqq Wolf\grqq &
    \flq lup\frq\space\textipa{/lup/} \textipa{[lup]} &
    \flq lupi\frq\space\textipa{/lupi/} \textipa{[lup\textsuperscript{j}]} \\[5pt]
\hline
    \glqq Bär\grqq &
    \flq urs\frq\space\textipa{/urs/} \textipa{[urs]} &
    \flq urși\frq\space\textipa{/ursi/} \textipa{[urS\textsuperscript{j}]} \\[5pt] 
\hline
    \glqq Elefant\grqq &
    \flq elefant\frq\space\textipa{/ElEfant/} \textipa{[ElEfant]} &
    \flq elefanți\frq\space\textipa{/ElEfanti/} \textipa{[ElEfan\texttoptiebar{ts}\textsuperscript{j}]} \\[5pt]
\hline
    \glqq junger Bock\grqq &
    \flq ied\frq\space\textipa{/ied/} \textipa{[\textsubarch{i}ed]} &
    \flq iezi\frq\space\textipa{/iedi/} \textipa{[\textsubarch{i}ez\textsuperscript{j}]} \\[5pt]
\hline
    \glqq Krebs\grqq &
    \flq rac\frq\space\textipa{/rak/} \textipa{[rak]} &
    \flq raci\frq\space\textipa{/raki/} \textipa{[ra\texttoptiebar{tS}\textsuperscript{j}]} \\[5pt]
\hline
    \glqq Hamster\grqq &
    \flq hârciog\frq\space\textipa{/h\textbari r\texttoptiebar{tS}og/} \textipa{[h\textbari r\texttoptiebar{tS}og]} &
    \flq hârciogi\frq\space \textipa{/h\textbari r\texttoptiebar{tS}ogi/} \textipa{[h\textbari r\texttoptiebar{tS}o\texttoptiebar{dZ}\textsuperscript{j}]} \\[5pt]
\hline
\end{tabular}
    \label{konalt}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `p` (or `b`) columns for such a table not `m` as `m` loses baseline alignment. Also your specified widths made the table wider than the text width, so I reduced them a bit.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,numbers=endperiod]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm,footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[footnote,printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
  \setlength\extrarowheight{6pt}
    \caption{Konsonantische Alternationen bei der Pluralbildung}
\begin{tabular}{ | M{2.7cm} | M{5.9cm} | M{5.9cm} | }
\hline
     &
    Singular &
    Plural \\
\hline
    \glqq Wolf\grqq &
    \flq lup\frq\space\textipa{/lup/} \textipa{[lup]} &
    \flq lupi\frq\space\textipa{/lupi/} \textipa{[lup\textsuperscript{j}]} \\[5pt]
\hline
    \glqq Bär\grqq &
    \flq urs\frq\space\textipa{/urs/} \textipa{[urs]} &
    \flq urși\frq\space\textipa{/ursi/} \textipa{[urS\textsuperscript{j}]} \\[5pt] 
\hline
    \glqq Elefant\grqq &
    \flq elefant\frq\space\textipa{/ElEfant/} \textipa{[ElEfant]} &
    \flq elefanți\frq\space\textipa{/ElEfanti/} \textipa{[ElEfan\texttoptiebar{ts}\textsuperscript{j}]} \\[5pt]
\hline
    \glqq junger Bock\grqq &
    \flq ied\frq\space\textipa{/ied/} \textipa{[\textsubarch{i}ed]} &
    \flq iezi\frq\space\textipa{/iedi/} \textipa{[\textsubarch{i}ez\textsuperscript{j}]} \\[5pt]
\hline
    \glqq Krebs\grqq &
    \flq rac\frq\space\textipa{/rak/} \textipa{[rak]} &
    \flq raci\frq\space\textipa{/raki/} \textipa{[ra\texttoptiebar{tS}\textsuperscript{j}]} \\[5pt]
\hline
    \glqq Hamster\grqq &
    \flq hârciog\frq\space\textipa{/h\textbari r\texttoptiebar{tS}og/} \textipa{[h\textbari r\texttoptiebar{tS}og]} &
    \flq hârciogi\frq\space \textipa{/h\textbari r\texttoptiebar{tS}ogi/} \textipa{[h\textbari r\texttoptiebar{tS}o\texttoptiebar{dZ}\textsuperscript{j}]} \\[5pt]
\hline
\end{tabular}
    \label{konalt}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of specifying a per-row spacing adjustment using `\\[<len>]`, we can add a strut to each entry of a particular column. The strut could stretch vertically below and above the baseline in order to stretch the line spacing exactly as needed:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\heightadjustment}{\rule[-12pt]{0pt}{2.5\normalbaselineskip}}
\begin{tabular}{ | >{\heightadjustment}M{49mm} | M{49mm} | M{49mm} | }
  \hline
  & \textit{Something} & \textit{Something else} \\
  \hline
  Sprechsprache & (Phonem) & (Phon) \\
  \hline
  Schriftsprache & (Graphem) & (Graph) \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Here are the struts visualized in the first column (obtained by using a `1pt` width for the `\rule`, rather than `0pt`):

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! But there is still a problem in one of my tables that include \tipa{} elements. They still have the problem that the text in the last column is slightly higher than the rest.

Comment: @LajosH: You should play around with the lengths in the strut.

Comment: I did, but there is no change. No matter if I change the 0 to a 1 or a 10 or a 50 =/